# Anyone know the schedule for review of EU entry requirements?

Tags: covid-19, eu, austria, hungary

I am looking to enter Austria from the US and travel on to Budapest over the land border. This is possible as of right now, but my flight is not until July 25 and I'm concerned the rules might change in the meantime. I can bring the flight forward but will then end up paying for accommodation in two places at once.

Most countries seem to review their greenlists etc. on a set schedule. Does anyone know when these reviews take place a) at EU level, b) in Austria, c) in Hungary?

PS I appreciate that the EU decisions are not binding but am still interested in that aspect of it.

Comment: The EU list is supposed to be revised every two weeks (https://www.etiasvisa.com/etias-news/eu-entry-restrictions), although the same site says that the most recent list came out on 18 June, which is now just over two weeks ago. They still have an "emergency brake" mechanism to deal with sudden changes. The UK had a similar set up last year and I guess it still does - don't know about Austria or Hungary though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.